# How do i fix the error in replace regex flag component?

Tags: nutch

I am using nutch 1.14 since I am using GCS indexer. Here is what I have in nutch-site.xml

```
<property>  
    <name>index.replace.regexp</name>  
    <value>  
        urlmatch=.*example.com\/[a-zA-Z0-9-]+  
        url:category=/https:\/\/www.example.com\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$1/  
    </value>  
</property>
```

I am getting the error:

```
$ grep 'replace' logs/hadoop.log  
ERROR replace.ReplaceIndexer - Pattern           
url:category=/https:\/\/www.example.com\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$1/, has invalid flags component
```

I get the same when i change the line in nutch-site.xml to:

```
-url:category=/https:\/\/www.mydomain.com\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$1/2
```

I want to get part of url in category. Ex: If url is https://www.example.com/testcategory , i like category to be testcategory

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to get what is after the domain (example.com) and place it in a category field, right?

In that case, you have an error in your regex. You want to capture everything after `example.com/<category>` then you need to configure your `urlmatch` like:

```
urlmatch=.*example\.com\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)
```

In this case `([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)` will create a capture group accessible through `$1`. And then you can set the field like:

```
 url:category=$1
```

This would get what was captured with the capture group and place it a `category` field.

You can test the regex in: https://regex101.com/r/bMLqOq/1.

Comment: Thanks Jorge!  Is there an easy way to stdout (or log) what is captured in category without changing and recompiling the nutch code?

Comment: Are you running Nutch locally or in distributed mode? If you're running Nutch locally you don't need to recompile.

Comment: I am running locally.  $bin/nutch readseg -get TestCrawl/segments/*  category shows nothing.